# $a_{ij}=i $ if $i+j=n+1$ and $0$ otherwise; compute det $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The entries of the matrix is specified by this rule,

> > $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb R)$,
> >
> > $a_{ij}=i$ if $i+j=n+1$
> >
> > and $0$ otherwise.
>
> Compute det $A$
>
> >
>   I have seen for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7......$;det A= $1,-2!,-3!,4!,5!,-6!,-7!,......$ How can i express it in acompact manner?

Comment: Have you tried using indicial notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$A = \pmatrix{0&&1\\&\cdot&\\n&&0}$$
So
$$\det A = (-1)^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \det \pmatrix{n&&0\\&\ddots&\\0&&1} = (-1)^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} n!$$
Where the $(-1)^{\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor}$ is the sign of the inversion permutation $i\mapsto n-i+1$ wich is the product of $\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ swapping permutations $\tau_{i, n-i+1}$

Comment: Note that if you don't like floors, you can write $(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}=(-1)^\binom n2$.